# How to find ami id using shell script

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, awk, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

How to find ami id using shell script

My Script :

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/amidel.txt); do
        echo "Image ID of instance which needed to be Deregistered is $i ";
        val1="$i"-i-*
        aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=$val1" | awk '{ print  $11 }' 
done
```

Now Issue is that "aws ec2 describe-images" returns image id for different awk value :

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=instance-20Aug15-i-*" |  awk '{ print  $9 }'
```

Output :

```
ami-xxxx

$ aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=instance-18Aug15-i-*" |  awk '{ print  $11 }'
```

Output :

```
ami-xxxx
```

This is happening because third value returned by "aws ec2 describe-images" is Comment which varies for each ami image :

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=instance-18Aug15-i-*"
```

Output :

```
IMAGES  x86_64  This is for Daily auto AMI creation xen ami-bebfb1ec    008392659736/instance-18Aug15-i-1effb6d3    machine aki-503e7402    instance-18Aug15-i-1effb6d3 008392659736    False   /dev/sda1   ebs available   paravirtual
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPINGS /dev/sda1
EBS True    snap-51539764   8   gp2
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPINGS /dev/sdf
EBS False   snap-4e95d37b   20  gp2
```

For 2nd Ami :

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=instance-20Aug15-i-*"
```

Output :

```
IMAGES  x86_64  This is created by ami-backup.sh    xen ami-52020b00    008392659736/instance-20Aug15-i-127fb8df    machine instance-20Aug15-i-127fb8df 008392659736    False   /dev/sda1   ebs simple  available   hvm
BLOCKDEVICEMAPPINGS /dev/sda1
EBS True    snap-2b563aca   8   gp2
```

So please help me how parse this to get proper ami id or is there any other method to find ami id from ami name ?

Comment: `awk '/ami-[[:alnum:]]+/{match($0,/.*(ami-[[:alnum:]]+).*/,a); print a[1]}'` may be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` is an inappropriate tool to parse JSON. [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would be substantially more appropriate if you like chaining tools.

You can [change the output format returned by aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html). That makes awk/grep more appropriate.

[You can also use `--query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter) instead of trying to parse it through `awk`. It uses the [JMESPath syntax](http://jmespath.org/specification.html), which is slightly easier than the `jq` syntax.

Here's some examples:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-6b1cd400 --query Images[].ImageId
[
    "ami-6b1cd400"
]

$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-6b1cd400 --query Images[].ImageId --output text
ami-6b1cd400
```

Answer (score 2):

We can find AMI id by using AWS CLI and jQuery.
I have managed to solve this with the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --output json | jq '.Images[] | {ImageId}' | jq --raw-output '.ImageId'
```